# Is it possible to remove just one RXJS Observer from an Observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

If I have a service containing an Observable and I have the following code...

```
    this.collapse.newChild.subscribe(name => {
        if (name === "helpArea") {
            this.collapse.process("helpArea", true);
        }
        // I would like to detach now
    });
```

Is it possible to detach without canceling the original subscription? If I call `unsubscribe` then when I call `this.collapse.newChild.next("thing")` it throws an error `Error: object unsubscribed`.

So I don't think unsubscribe is what I am looking for, so is there a way to detach a single observer?

As a work around for now I am using...

`this.collapse.newChild.map(name => name === "helpArea").first().subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your "workaround" is at all bad. It even seems idiomatic: the way that Rx *wants* you to do it. But you can write it a bit shorter, using the form of `first` that takes a predicate.

```
this.collapse.newChild
         .first(name => name === "helpArea")
         .subscribe(...);
```

In general, the mindset to get into with Rx is to as much as possible use combinators to manipulate streams to produce exactly the values that you need, and then subscribe with a simple handler that applies the final, effectful, step: updating the UI, calling a service etc. This will lead to cleaner, more expressive code, that is easier to read and easier to re-use.

Another nice thing about this approach for your example is that there is no need to unsubscribe. RX will do that for you after the first value because it knows there won't be more. So it's much cleaner than doing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Peter answer is correct from a design/practice PoV, but beware also that you get this error because you `unsubscribe` the subject.

What you want to stop is the subscription instead:

```
var subscription = this.collapse.newChild.subscribe(...)

// NOT this
// this.collapse.newChild.unsubscribe()

// this
subscription.unsuscribe()
```

This will kill/stop not the subject, but only your current subscription to it.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `unsubscribe()` on a Subscription object unsubscribes only this particular observer. So a question is how did you unsubscribed at the first place because using `first()` sends complete notification which causes unsubscription anyway.

Btw, you can always unsubscribe inside your own subscriber's callback:

```
var subscription = this.collapse.newChild.subscribe(name => {
    if (name === "helpArea") {
        this.collapse.process("helpArea", true);
    }
    subscription.unsubscribe();
});
```